# Inline Images in Quarto Markdown

Tags: r, quarto

I need to place an inline image in a apresentation in Quarto (Revealjs) but every inline image shows displaced a bit upwards:

[image]

the code I wrote is:

```
I want an inline image but I get: ![](images/RStudio_logo.svg){height=30}
```

I can't find the information in the documentation and I am not proficient in css.

the question is: Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add in your yaml a css file which looks like this:

**styles.css**

```
.center{
  margin: 0!important;
  height: 30px;
}
```

and add it to your yaml like this:

```
---
format: revealjs
css: styles.css
---
```

then you can add it to your image

```
I want an inline image but I get: ![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/RStudio_logo_flat.svg){.center}
```

[image]

---

*Explanation*:

The reason why this happens is the internal css-style of quarto. The above written code overwrites the existing style (that was it is necessary to use `!important`), that looks like this

```
.reveal img {
  margin: var(--r-block-margin) 0;
}
```

Therefore, we use an own css style for that image to override that default.

Comment: This works! Thank you! It seems easier to just build a style.css files with all the custom styles I need than to do it for every image.

Comment: The new explanation of why to use `!important` is very helpful. Thanks again.